# Novel on generational ship with a character named "Spinner of Rope"

Tags: story-identification

The title says it all. I'm trying to remember the title of a book that took place on a generational ship. So much time had passed that the new generations forgot they were on a spacecraft. A distinct culture emerged. A young boy named "Spinner of Rope" from that culture stumbled upon the truth of their situation.

Any hints?

Comment: There is a character called _Spinner-of-Rope_ in Stephen Baxter's novel [Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(Baxter_novel)) but this doesn't match your description.

Comment: @JohnRennie Hmm... I must be remembering it wrong. I have read Ring, so that must be it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. I'll mark this as a duplicate of _Ring_.